# How to disable telnet on a Debian 11

Tags: debian, services, telnet

As per title, how can I disable telnet on a Debian 11 server?

I think I can (how?) block port using ufw, but... how can I disable the *service* itself?

I tried

```
systemctl disable telnet
```

But

```
Failed to disable unit: Unit file telnet.service does not exist.
```

EDIT

I am ahppy to receive an answer even if the question is stupid. I had the dubt that service was running even if I'm not able to detect at my first attemp.

The answer I accepetd is simple, give me an explanation and a solution.

Comment: There is nothing to disable unless you installed and enabled the service in the first place.

Comment: @muru: thanks. In this case this was the simplest, and rightest answer. If something is obvious for who read the question, do not be so arrogant to think it was obvious for who is asking. If I didn't have the dubt, I didn't ask.

Comment: Well, we'd expect that people wouldn't be so lazy as to not check what's installed on their own servers before posting.

Comment: @muru it's not lazyness. I have no idea of how to check 'other things' ... sorry for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Debian, the various `telnet` server implementations don’t use systemd to provide their services, they are configured as `inetd` services. So if they *are* installed, you can’t use `systemctl` to disable them.

However, they are all packaged as single-purpose packages. So the best approach to ensure that `telnet` servers are disabled in Debian is to check that the corresponding packages aren’t installed:

```
sudo apt purge '*telnetd*'
```

Comment: Simple and working solution !

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Failed to disable unit: Unit file telnet.service does not exist.
> ```

The error message tells you the reason for the failure is that the "*Unit file telnet.service does not exist*". You don't have a `telnet` service installed (by that name, if at all) so it's not possible to disable it.

You can check this with `netstat -na` or `ss -na` to confirm that there is nothing listening on TCP port 23. For example, this command will return results only if there is something listening on port 23:

```
ss -na | grep LISTEN | grep -w 23
```

If there is something reported then please update your question with the command you used and its output.

Comment: To be fair, a telnet server might well have a service called `telnetd.service` rather than `telnet.service`; the absence of `telnet.service` isn’t conclusive proof that no `telnet` server is installed.

Comment: @StephenKitt fair comment. Let's see if the OP returns after having investigated with `netstat` or `ss`; if positive I'm happy to delete or extensively modify this answer

Comment: I don’t think your answer warrants deleting (I upvoted it), it explains the error message and gives a way to check for anything listening on port 23, which is conclusive!