# blocking telnet service using firewalld

Tags: linux, firewalld

my zone in firewalld in public and the list is like below.

```
firewall-cmd --list-all

public (active)
  
target: default

icmp-block-inversion: no

interfaces: enp0s3 enp0s8
 
sources:
 
services: dhcpv6-client redis ssh
 
ports:

protocols:
 
masquerade: no

forward-ports:

source-ports:

icmp-blocks:

rich rules:
```

I want to block telnet communication.
How can i do that?
It's worth to mention that i can telnet to this server right now with this zone.

Comment: It should block it already, I don't know what the problem is. 1) Can you edit your post, to add what Linux you are using, and the version number?  2) Does `systemctl restart firewalld` show an error?  3) After the restart, is there a recent error message in `journalctl -b -u firewalld` ?

Comment: what do you call "telnet communication" ? do you speak of age old telnet protocol with clear password transmitted ? This one has been disabled by default 15 years ago of many distribution. You have to explicitly allow it should you need it.

Comment: Right. 1) If you don't want to run a telnet service at all, it would be best to disable it. 2) Most people should not run a telnet service. 3) Since your firewalld *should* block the telnet service, can you just confirm exactly what it looks like when you telnet to this server, from your other computer?

Answer (score 1):

You can block port 23 or block the service

Port:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=23/tcp --permanent`

Service:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=telnet --permanent`

`--permanent` ensures that the rule persists across reboots.

Reload firewall `firewall-cmd --reload`

Check this post for disable:

[How to disable telnet on a Debian 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/667460/515538)

[How to remove access to a port using firewall](https://serverfault.com/questions/818996/how-to-remove-access-to-a-port-using-firewall-on-centos7)

**Edit:**

This rule should rejects all incoming tcp traffic from any source address on port 23.

**ipv4:**

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="0.0.0.0/0" port port="23" protocol="tcp" reject' --permanent`

**ipv6:**

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv6" source address="::/0" port port="23" protocol="tcp" reject' --permanent`

[Configuring Complex Firewall Rules with the "Rich Language" Syntax](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/configuring_complex_firewall_rules_with_the_rich-language_syntax)

[Firewalld Rich Rules Explained with Examples](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/firewalld-rich-rules-explained-with-examples.html)

[How To Use Firewalld Rich Rules And Zones For Filtering And NAT](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-use-firewalld-rich-rules-and-zones-for-filtering-and-nat/)

Comment: as you see, The problem is according to my zone,there is no telnet service or port 23.I also run your command but it doesn't work